# Links in python

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, trim

I got a regex which is suitable for getting the Hyperlinks in a page source.

When I run this piece of code

```
import sys,re
import webpage_get

def print_links(page):

    print '[+] print_links()'
    links = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+',page)
    links.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(links)), 'HyperLinks Found:'
    a = open(r'C:\Users\noh\Desktop\ApplicationDevelopment\Second Course work\result.txt','w')
    for link in links:
        a.write(link)
    a.close()

def main():
    sys.argv.append('http://socrdlvideo.napier.ac.uk/~csn11118/CSN08115/index.html')
##    sys.argv.append('http://www.napier.ac.uk/Pages/home.aspx')

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] usage: webpage_getlinks URL'
        return

    page = webpage_get.wget(sys.argv[1])
    print_links(page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result will be similar to this:

```
href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars/trailer/">Star Wars Trailer</a>
```

What I really need is just the link itself without the addition strings in both sides, for instance:

```
http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars/trailer/
```

It would be great if you tell me how to get rid of the addition strings in both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=href=\")http.*?\/(?=\")
```

Or this one:

```
http.*?\/(?=\")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YXw2y5/1

So, in your code, change this line:

```
links = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+',page)
```

to this:

```
links = re.findall(r'(?<=href=\")http.*?\/(?=\")',page)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that your pattern cannot parse correctly.

use pattern: `href\=.*(http\:.+)\"` replace `<a.*href\=.*http\:.+`

Try using this pattern: https://regex101.com/r/WT1AQ7/1

PS: using `()` to group the actual thing you want.

Comment: Actually I am not so good with Regex, I just copied this one from THE web, can you help me with it?? can you copy the pattern here I tried opening the link but there was nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'href="(http.+?)"', string=your string)
```

use () to capture want your need

```
import re
file = '''
 href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license">cc by-sa 3.0</a> 
                with <a href="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/" rel="license">attribution required</a> '''
matchs = re.findall(r'href="(http.+?)"', string=file)
for link in matchs:
    print(link)
```

out:

```
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/
```

the code works!!
please learn regex, not copy regex !

Comment: Please can you tell me where does it fit in the code??

Comment: links = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+',page) string = page

Comment: it's not helpful, i still cannot understand which spot of the code it should be located